# SOQL - How to retrieve CaseNumber based on the ParentId and Name based ContactId?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm extracting the "**Id**", "**CaseNumber**", "**ContactId**" & "**ParentId**" variables from "**Case**" object:

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, ContactId, ParentId FROM Case
```

| Id | CaseNumber | ContactId | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5004V000000000000A | 00000001 | 003300000000000000 | #N/A |
| 5004V000000000000B | 00000002 | 003300000000000000 | 5004V000000000000A |

But instead of display the ID string of the "**ParentId**", I need to display the *CaseNumber* whose the "**Id**" of corresponding "**ParentId**" belongs to.

Using the above example as a reference, by replacing the "**ParentId**" by the *ParentCaseNumber* the desired result would be:

| Id | CaseNumber | ContactId | `ParentCaseNumber` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5004V000000000000A | 00000001 | 003300000000000000 | #N/A |
| 5004V000000000000B | 00000002 | 003300000000000000 | ***00000001*** |

Additionally, instead of displaying the "**ContactId**" I need to display the *ContactName*. I know there is a "**Name**" variable inside the "**User**" object that matches the "**ContactId**" provided by "**Case**" object query.

"**User**" object query example:

```
SELECT Id, ContactId, Name FROM User`
```

| Id | ContactId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 005300000000000000 | 003300000000000000 | John Smith |

So I need to replace "**ContactId**" returned by the "**Case**" object query by the "**Name**" found on "User" object as above. The desired query output result would be:

| Id | CaseNumber | `ContactName` | ParentCaseNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5004V000000000000A | 00000001 | ***John Smith*** | #N/A |
| 5004V000000000000B | 00000002 | ***John Smith*** | 00000001 |

Anyone could help me to build a SOQL query to accomplish such result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Contact.Name, Parent.CaseNumber
FROM Case
```

You need to read up a bit about [relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) which is Salesforce's way of doing joins between tables.

You can go "up" 5 times, have 5 dots (`SELECT Account.Owner.Profile.Name FROM Case`). And you can go "down" the related lists too (`SELECT Id, (SELECT Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account`

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/create-relationship-queries-with-standard-objects and https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql may help.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Thank you for providing the additional reference links.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query and let us know how it turns out for you. We have tested this in an org and it works without complication. Have a blessed one.

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Contact.Name, Parent.CaseNumber FROM Case
```